# Maintainability index for over all angular.js project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, maintainability

For one of my research project I have been told to find maintainability index, Mc cabe cyclomatic complexity and helsatead metric of angular.js project for entire project. Any ideas for tools to use i searched on Google came up with Microsoft visual studio but we have to buy it in order to use full feature or use evaluated version. I Am looking for any free software available on internet that would give me all the above result or atleast 3 of them so I can find MI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout npm package plato https://github.com/es-analysis/plato.

It will give you maintainability index, code complexity and other metrics. You can see sample reports for some popular libraries like jQuery which has a maintainability of 78.81.

See it here http://es-analysis.github.io/plato/examples/jquery/

Comment: Hello @Bhabishya Kumar i am getting this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629209/plato-software-error